# spring + jpa + hibernate, listing all rows in a table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to read all values of rows, from the table Person in a db.
I think the configuration persistence.xml and Entry.java (entity) is correct. If needed I will post them.
Anyway my code doesn't work:

```
@Override
public List<Entry> list() {
    List<Entry> res = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Person", Entry.class).getResultList();

    return res;
}
```

log says:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM Person]
```

any idea ?

ok. Without SELECT * logs tell me:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Person is not mapped [FROM Person]
```

solved. The solution is :

```
        List<Entry> res = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Entry").getResultList();
```

Where "Entry" is the entity and not the table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `SELECT *` part from the query:

```
List<Entry> res = entityManager.createQuery("from Person", Entry.class).getResultList();
```

[JBoss JPA/Hibernate Tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the select clause:

```
List<Entry> res = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Person", Entry.class).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without select *

```
List<Entry> res = entityManager.createQuery("from Entry", Entry.class).getResultList();
```

or with an alias :

```
List<Entry> res = entityManager.createQuery("select e from Entry e", Entry.class).getResultList();
```